# Need help to make permission conditions in PHP

Tags: php

I am building a computer inventory system for a small company. All of my codes are working fine except I don't know how to implement one important aspect, permission.

This is new_admin.php

```
<?php require_once("includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/dbconnection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php confirm_logged_in(); ?>

<?php require_once("header.php"); ?>

<?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

            $username= $_POST['username'];

            $password = $_POST["password"];

            $hashed_password = password_encrypt($password);

            $permissions = isset($_POST)?implode(",",$_POST['permissions']):"";
            //echo $permissions;

            if(!empty($username) && !empty($hashed_password) && !empty($permissions)) {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO admins (Admin_Username, Admin_Password, Admin_Permissions) VALUES ('$username', '$hashed_password', '$permissions')";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);          
                    if($result) {
                        redirect_to("manage_admins.php");
                    } else {
                        echo "Error while creating new admin";
                    }
            } else {
                echo "Username, password and permissions can not be blank!";

            } 
        } else {

        }
?>
<h2>Create New Admin</h2>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="35%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <td>Username</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="30">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="30">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Permissions</td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="read" id="permissions_0">
          Read</label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="create" id="permissions_1">
        Create</label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="update" id="permissions_2">
        Update </label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="delete" id="permissions_3">
        Delete</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2"><label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Create Admin">
      </label></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <a href="manage_admins.php">Cancel</a>
</form>
<?php require_once("footer.php"); ?>
```

This is manage_admins.php

```
<?php require_once("includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/dbconnection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php confirm_logged_in(); ?>
<?php require_once("header.php"); ?>


    <a href="admin.php">&laquo; Main Page</a>
<h2>Manage Admins</h2>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">Username</th>
        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left;">Action</th>
      </tr>
    <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM admins ORDER BY Admin_Username ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        $admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        /*
        echo $admin['Admin_Permissions'];
        Output: create,read,update,delete
        */
        while($admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo htmlentities($admin["Admin_Username"]); ?></td>
        <td><a href="edit_admin.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($admin["id"]); ?>">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="delete_admin.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($admin["id"]); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this admin?');">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <br />

    <a href="new_admin.php">Add new admin</a>

<?php require_once("footer.php"); ?>
```

I've tried using 
if(in_array("delete", $admin['Admin_Permissions'])) {
but i get the following error : in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

How do I check the permission from database so that if the admin doesn't have "delete" permission, he can not perform "delete admin" & if the admin doesn't have "update" permission, he can not perform "Edit."

Comment: Database columns can't contain arrays, so `$admin['Admin_Permissions']` can't be an array. What is the value of this column? If it's a comma-separated list, use `explode()` to make an array of the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Admin_Permissions" field is a string. As per your code, value might be "read,create,update,delete"

**Using inArray, 2nd param should be array, so your code should be like this**

```
$permissions = explode(",", $admin['Admin_Permissions']);
if(in_array("delete", $permissions)){
  //code here
}
```